# call two functions in one URL route

Tags: php, mysql, routes

I'm new to php, twig, routing and mvc and I have a problem that I can't seem to solve.

My 1st problem is I don't know how to get the artist name from the link so I can filter mysql query by artist.
2nd problem is how I can call another function ('searchSongList') on the same route.

My aim is when I click on a song link it loads another page that shows info of the song and then a list of songs by the artist.

HTML link:

' a href="/play?id={{ song.ID_song }}" class="song-link" '

My route:

```
'play' => ['GeneralController', 'searchSongById', ['id']],
```

that calls 'searchSongById' to get song info by id :

```
public function searchSongById(int $id): string
{
    $GeneralManager = new GeneralManager();
    $song = $GeneralManager->selectSongById($id);

    return $this->twig->render('General/playPage.html.twig', ['song' => $song]);
}

public function selectSongById(int $id): array | false
{
    // prepared request
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT songs.ID_song , songs.title , songs.artist , genre.genre, songs.image_url, songs.song_url FROM songs
                                        join genre on songs.genre_ID_genre = genre.ID_genre
                                        WHERE songs.ID_song=:id");
    $statement->bindValue('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetch();
}
```

(which works) but then I need to call another function that gets a list of songs by the artist.

```
public function searchSongList(string $artist)
{
        $GeneralManager = new GeneralManager();
        $songs = $GeneralManager->getsongList($artist);

        return $this->twig->render('General/searchPage.html.twig', ['songs' => $songs]);
}


public function getsongList():array
{
    $query = 'SELECT songs.ID_song , songs.title , songs.artist , genre.genre
    FROM songs
    join genre on songs.genre_ID_genre = genre.ID_genre
    where songs.artist like "%:artist%';

    return $this->pdo->query($query)->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: You mean the second function works but you don't know how to get `:artist` value, is it?

Comment: Do another join with `songs` table matching the `artist` value on the second function and reuse `ID_song = :id` as reference, for example `...  FROM songs s1 JOIN songs s2 ON s1.artist=s2.artist JOIN genre g1 on s2.genre_ID_genre = g1.ID_genre
    WHERE s1.ID_song = :id;`

Comment: I want to run both functions 'searchSongById' and 'searchSongList' on the same route. But yes also find a way to get the artist name.

Comment: Perhaps you could just do a single query from db and handle the view in PHP. Let's say that maybe in your front-end, the user is supposed to see the exact song info on top and the rest of songs matching the same artist listed at the bottom. So, you probably can do "if song_id match, show the info in this <div>", then for the song list "if song_id don't match, show them as list in this <div>"?

Comment: I want to show both the song info and a list of songs by the artist on the same page.

Comment: I tried your query example and it doesn't work on mysql. I get Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'songs.ID_song' in 'field list'

Comment: Actually, my suggestion includes assigning aliases on each table so, the first `songs` table is now `s1`, the second `songs` table is `s2` and `genre` table is `g1`. To get the value from first table you should write `s1.ID_song` instead of `songs.ID_song` because once the table assigned with alias, you use that alias in place for the table name.

Comment: Thats what i did i used s1.ID_song and it still gave me the error message.

Comment: Your error returns `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'songs.ID_song' in 'field list'`. Maybe in the `SELECT ` part.

Comment: Thanks @FanoFN your query helped me find the songs by artist using song id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I managed to load song info and a list of songs by the artist name onto one page.

HTML link:

' a href="/play?id={{ song.ID_song }}" class="song-link" '

My route:

'play' => ['GeneralController', 'getSongsForPlayPage', ['id']],

Functions and their queries:

```
public function getSongsForPlayPage(int $id): string
{

        $GeneralManager = new GeneralManager();
        $song = $GeneralManager->selectSongById($id);
        $GeneralManagerSongs = new GeneralManager();
        $artistSongs = $GeneralManagerSongs->getsongList($id);

        return $this->twig->render('General/playPage.html.twig', ['song' => $song, 'artistSongs' => $artistSongs]);
}

public function selectSongById(int $id): array | false
{
    // prepared request
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT songs.ID_song , songs.title , songs.artist , genre.genre, songs.image_url, songs.song_url FROM songs
                                        join genre on songs.genre_ID_genre = genre.ID_genre
                                        WHERE songs.ID_song=:id");
    $statement->bindValue('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetch();
}

public function getsongList(int $id):array | false
{

    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT s2.ID_song , s2.title , s2.artist , g1.genre
    FROM songs s1 
    JOIN songs s2 ON s1.artist=s2.artist 
    JOIN genre g1 on s2.genre_ID_genre = g1.ID_genre
    WHERE s1.ID_song=:id");
    $statement->bindValue('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetchAll();
}
```